# History for my application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, save

I'm trying to make a history for my app. Whenever the user calculates the calorie per hour rate, I want that to be stored into another activities listview. How can I do that?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Monitor.this);
alertDialog.setTitle(gotNames);
alertDialog.setMessage("You are currently burning " + caloriesForMen() 
    + " calories per hour");
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }   
});
```

Write when the hit the save button, I want to take the value of caloriesForMen().toString() and put it in a listview. Now, this info is specific only to a selected user. There are multiple users and I"m wondering how I can store the values of their calorie burn rate in a listview and save them for each user created. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: have you considered using SQLite?

Comment: create hashmap and store the values based on the userId(key) create a custom object to store the value.it is for temp purpose otherwise u can store it database or server side

Comment: @Taruni I know I need to store it, but I don't know how. I've tried using my database, but how am I going to save multiple values to one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes most sense to store the data persistently on the device. Otherwise, if you just keep it in memory, the data would be lost if the system stops your application.

There are several possibilities like using files, shared preferences or an SQLite database.
The other activity with the list view would read the data from the persistent storage.

The [API Guide on Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/index.html) describes the details.

Storing data on a server makes sense if you want to share it between different devices.

Comment: Can you show me some sample code? I know where you're going with this, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: If you follow the link I have posted you will also find example code.

Comment: I have a database created to store the users inputted name, weight, age, and gender, but how can I store the values for their calorie burn rate? There's obviously going to be more than one value depending on how many times they click the save button.

Comment: wenever user clicks on save button check in databasae whether the user is already existed or not by the userId , if the user is already existed update that row with new data or u can add one more row to maintain all the calorie burn rates

Comment: Use a second table for that. For each user you would have several records (rows) in it. One of the columns in this second table is the ID of the user in the first table in order to be able to connect the two.

Comment: I see, so I'm going to need to create another table and have two columns: the id and calorie burn rate for that specific user.

Comment: yes exactly. You can also store additional information like a time stamp when the button was pressed (if this is useful for your app)

Comment: Thank you, if I have any more questions I'll get back to you

Comment: Ok, so I got the listview to show the calorie burn rate, now how can I only show the calorie burn rate only for the selected user in the listview?

Comment: When you fetch the rows from the database you can specify selection criteria. In your case the userId in the row must be the same as the ID of the selected user.

Comment: OMG dude thank you so much!! You got me where I wanted, you're the best!